# Qual a diferença entre utilizar uma ou duas Arrow Functions no UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

[Nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364492), utiliza-se um `useEffect` com duas *arrow functions* seguidas. Assim:

> ```
> useEffect(() => () => {
>   window.removeEventListener('resize', compareSize);
> }, []);
> ```

Gostaria de saber porque a dupla *arrow function* está sendo utilizada ali em cima. Qual a diferença entre um `useEffect` com somente uma *arrow function* para um `useEffect` com duas *arrow functions* (conforme o exemplo acima)?

Por exemplo, este:

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>   compareSize();
>   window.addEventListener('resize', compareSize);
> }, []);
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sabe-se que funções retornadas pela função que se passa ao `useEffect` são utilizadas pelo React como o *cleanup effect*, ou seja, será executada quando o componente for desmontado.

Portanto, fazer:

```
// Este `useEffect` só executa código em cleanup
useEffect(() => () => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', compareSize);
});
```

É o mesmo que isto:

```
// Este `useEffect` só executa código em cleanup
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', compareSize);
  };
});
```

---

Dessarte, os dois `useEffect`s da pergunta podem ser "fundidos" em um só, assim:

```
useEffect(() => {
  compareSize();
  window.addEventListener('resize', compareSize);
  
  // Efeito de cleanup:
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', compareSize);
  };
}, []);
```

---

Para entender melhor a sintaxe, veja o que são [*arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Sobre os efeitos de *cleanup* e `useEffect` no geral, referir à [documentação do React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).